# Multiply a number by n values in a for loop in Java

Tags: java, for-loop, multiplication

I have:

```
salary = 2000;
n= salary/200 = 10 //number of loops;
contribution = 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4...;
```

I need to make a for loop that gets the sum of salary x contribution as:

salary x contribution1 = 500x0.1
salary x contribution2 = 500x0.2
...etc...

this is a method of my class:

```
public static double pensionContribution(double salary) {
        
        
    double n = salary/200;
    int n_round = (int) Math.floor(n);
        
    int start = 1;
    List<Integer> n_list = IntStream.rangeClosed(start, n_round)
                .boxed().collect(Collectors.toList());
        
        
    double counter = 0.1;
        
    for (int i = 0; i < n_list.size(); i++) {
           System.out.println(n_list.get((int) (salary*counter)));
                 
    }
        counter = counter + 0.1;
        //need the sum of all values of (salary*counter)
        
    return n_round;
            
    }
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use this loop:

```
for(int i = 0;i < [times to loop];i++){

     resultofmultiplication = (salary*counter)
     sum = sum + resultofmultiplication
     counter = counter + 0.1

}
return sum;
```

you will get all the results from the multiplications summed. idk why you need a list but this will give you the sum of the multiplications

Comment: maybe I thought a list was the better option because i'm used to program with Python, and very newby in Java.

Comment: You're missing a close parenthesis in for-loop condition.

Comment: That worked! Thanks! Just missing one parenthesis at the end of for statement.

Answer (score 0):

For each n in the list you need to calculate salary*n*0.1 and sum all.
This can be done in one stream:

```
public static double pensionContribution(double salary) {
    double n = salary/200;
    int n_round = (int) Math.floor(n);
    return IntStream.rangeClosed(1, n_round).mapToDouble(i->salary*i*0.1).sum();
}
```